# please prove the following equations of maths

Tags: modular-arithmetic

1. [(  ) − (  )]   = ( − ) ( )
2. [(  ) × (  )]   = ( × ) ( )

also I just want to confirm one answer
Is the answer of this equation
Q) 2 ≡ 2 ( 3)
MY answer: x=4 Is this correct answer?

Comment: You can find proofs for both (1) and (2) in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXUPr5JF40U

Comment: to see if your answer is correct, verify it yourself, correct answer does not need approval from others. Do not too many irrelevant tags

Comment: @zararana try using Euclidean division; you can write $a$ as $a = nx + p$ and $b$ as $b = ny + q$ and try those.

Comment: @Spectre sorry, i'm totally new in this topic. I didn't know much about this. Can you please help how or share some examples?

Comment: @jimjim I solved many parts by myself with the help of youtube tutorial. So, I want to confirm before submitting it to my teacher. Otherwise he will deduct my marks. I know its correct but I want to confirm?

Comment: @MattiP. Sorry, i didn't get the video

Comment: Show your work , maybe the answer is correct but how you got there is incorrect, then there should be no marks given .

Comment: @jimjim  ok i will show you here

Comment: @jimjim I have already typed up an answer (might be slightly wrong, I'm not sure); may I post it?

Comment: I can't keep suffering :D so I'd need your opinion as well

Comment: @Spectre, please if you can help me, please help

Comment: @zararana okay I'll try, but I tell you, make sure it's right. I'm still a grade 11 student and hence can't always be right since I'm learning

Comment: @jimjim were I right on doing so?? I doubt if I did anything against the CoC....

Comment: thanks @Spectre. I appreciate your effort thank you so much :)

Comment: @zararana I guess it didn't involve much effot.. .. it is from my grade 10 math lessons

Comment: @Spectre okay. Actually i'm doing someone's else assignment. So, it's difficult for me to solve without having lectures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129870/discussion-between-zara-rana-and-spectre).

Comment: @Spectre : The request was for the OP to  show some work, you sending answer deserved an upvote. You were perfectly right with answering, there is nothing in CoC against answering,  the problem was when someone  asks a question and doesnt show their effort or their work.

Comment: @jimjim but answering hw questions sounds like more against the CoC.. as I heard from the OP, she's doing a project of a friend who's ill (I'm not sure if it's right) and so I feel good that I helped

Comment: @Spectre : Answering  questions is  not against the CoC,  asking them without doing or showing any work is.

Comment: @jimjim thanks then.. I feel my heart beating better now :D

Comment: @Spectre :  If you have reasons that what you did was right just repeat the reasons and never worry.

Comment: @jimjim FYI, regarding answering low-quality questions, you're correct that it's not against the [Code of Conduct](https://math.stackexchange.com/conduct) (which is what I assume CoC stands for). Instead, please see [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/602049).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so yeah, I'll prove the first part. Try the next one by yourself.

You can write $a = nx + p $ and $b = ny + q$. Now as per the first qn, $a \bmod n = p, b \bmod n = q$ and hence $(a \bmod n - b \bmod n) \bmod = p - q \rightarrow(LHS)$. Also, $a-b = n(x - y) + p - q$ and hence observe that $(a - b) \bmod n = p - q \rightarrow(RHS)$; observe hat both the LHS and RHS are equal.

Now for the last part about verifying a solution, yes it's right, but to generalize it, you can have $x = 3k +1$.

Comment: FYI, please see [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/602049) regarding answering low-quality questions.